# Can't send appropriate cookies to API server with Next.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, next.js

I've an API express server hosted on api.mydomain.com and a Next.js website hosted on mydomain.com, my Next.js application makes a `getServerSideProps` request to my API to get page data that I want to display. I can set cookies for api.mydomain.com but I can't send them back to the express API, I can only send cookies stored in mydomain.com, how do I properly set cookies that my API can use?

Server configuration:

```
const app = express()
app.use(cookieParser())

app.use(cors({
    origin: true,
    credentials: true
}))
```

Cookie-set route configuration:

```
res.cookie('language', req.params.lang, { expires: new Date(2025, 11) })
```

Data fetch route configuration:

```
router.get('/lang/:lang', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const content = await PageContent.find({ language: (req.params.lang.toLowerCase() || 'en') })
        res.send(content)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(404).send()
    }
})
```

Next.js configuration:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    const resContent = await fetch('api.mydomain.com/content/lang/' + 
    (context.req.cookies.language || 'en'), {
        credentials: 'include'
    })
    const contents = await resContent.json()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, I set the `domain: 'mydomain.com'` option on my Cookie-set route configuration and it worked, don't know if that's the best practice tho